# No module named 'nbformat.v1.convert' error for Snakemake rule

Tags: snakemake

I am receiving this error when I run my Snakefile:

```
Error in rule get_ha_frequency:
    jobid: 0
    output: freq.annotated.tsv

RuleException:
ModuleNotFoundError in line 29 of file/path/Snakefile:
No module named 'nbformat.v1.convert'
  File "file/path/Snakefile", line 29, in __rule_get_ha_frequency
  File "/home/users/USER/mambaforge/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "/home/users/USER/mambaforge/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbformat/v1/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "/home/users/USER/mambaforge/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

The Snakefile works without this rule. I haven't needed this module for any of my other rules and the script associated with this rule doesn't seem to be different than the other rules that are working (i.e. same input file type, same output file type, only module used is pandas). Why is nbformat necessary for this rule, but not the others? Is there a way to circumvent installing nbformat?

Comment: Please show your script as a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how, but something became messed up in the snakemake env and reinstalling snakemake helped fix this issue. I didn't even have to delete snakemake to reinstall. I just followed the Full Installation instructions [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html) and it gave me the option to replace my snakemake env with the fresh install.